# PCA via covariance matrix and PCA via SVD in python - how to obtain equal results

Tags: python, pca, svd, dimensionality-reduction

I want to perform a PCA an my dataset

```
XT.shape
->(2500,260)
```

The rows of the complex X contain the samples (2500), the columns of X contain the variables (260).
I perform SVD like this: (Python)

```
u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(XT)
proj_0 = np.dot(XT,vh)[:,0]
```

I thougth this would give me the projection of my data onto the first principle component. However, if I do a PCA using the covariance matrix:

```
cov = np.cov(XT, rowvar=False) 
eVals, eVecs = np.linalg.eigh(cov)

# Sort eigenvalues in decreasing order and eigenvectors alike
idx = np.argsort(np.abs(eVals))[::-1]
eVals = eVals[idx]
eVecs = eVecs[:,idx]

# Project data on eigenvectors
PCA_0 = np.dot(eVecs.T, XT.T).T[:,0]
```

Then PCA_0 and proj_0 do not yield the same results. So something I am missing, but what?

Comment: The error was: I have to mean-center the samples befor performing the PCA. Check this thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189822/how-does-centering-make-a-difference-in-pca-for-svd-and-eigen-decomposition

Comment: I am trying to do the same but in the case when in X the rows are the variables and the columns are the samples. In this case, I do the mean-centering across rows (since the rows are the variables) but then I have some trouble when trying to project the data on the PCs. Any idea?